# Robot "Headlights" in Gazebo

Tags: gazebo, simulation, urdf, simulator-gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to include headlights (or any type of mounted lighting fixture) on your robot model in Gazebo?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33731/robot-%22headlights%22-in-gazebo/) by [DimitriProsser](https://answers.ros.org/users/635/dimitriprosser/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11163 on 2012-05-10

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2012-05-12**:
Good question! It's a shame nobody seems to know the answer... maybe it would help to figure out how the simulated Prosilica pattern projector on the PR2 works (it seems to be "kind of" a light source, right?)

**Comment by [JonW](https://answers.ros.org/users/317/jonw/) on 2012-06-03**:
There is a gazebo_plugin called gazebo_ros_projector that looks like it may perform this function.  It appears to add an extra rendering pass to the scene to aplly such a texture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4759/attach-spotlights-to-robot-links-in-gazebo-19-ros/ and https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/issue/900/allow-attachment-of-lights-to-links

It looks like it has been recently added (updating this mid 2017), though I'm not sure which version of gazebo and ROS it will be available in (compiling gazebo from source could address that).

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2014-08-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0